# ThreeJs Raycaster not changing color of the touched boxes

Tags: three.js

```
//SCENE and CAMERA
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);




//GEOMETRIES
const boxGeo=new THREE.BoxGeometry(2,2)
const boxMat=new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial()
const box1=new THREE.Mesh(boxGeo,boxMat)
const box2=new THREE.Mesh(boxGeo,boxMat)
const box3=new THREE.Mesh(boxGeo,boxMat)
scene.add(box1)
scene.add(box2)
scene.add(box3)
box1.position.set(-7,0,0)
box3.position.set(7,0,0)


let objectsToTest=[box1,box2,box3]


const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor('#333333')

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
let clock=new THREE.Clock()

let tick = () => {
  controls.update();

  let elapsedTime=clock.getElapsedTime()
  

  const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
  const rayOrigin = new THREE.Vector3(-8, 0, 0);
  const rayDirection = new THREE.Vector3(10, 0, 0);
  rayDirection.normalize();
  raycaster.set(rayOrigin, rayDirection);
  let intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objectsToTest);
 
  for (let obj of objectsToTest){
  obj.material.color.set('blue')
 }
  for (let obj of intersects) {
   obj.object.material.color.set('pink')
  }


  box1.position.y = (Math.sin(elapsedTime/2)) * 5;
  box2.position.y = (Math.sin(elapsedTime/4)) * 5;
  box3.position.y = (Math.sin(-elapsedTime/3)) * 5;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  window.requestAnimationFrame(tick);
};
tick();
```

Initially they're all pink which I get is cuz they all start at the center.
Then all 3 of them turn pink even if one of them touches the ray, even if the rest of the boxes are far away from the ray.
How can I make only the one that is touching the ray pink?

Please ignore the below text

(Initially they're all pink which I get is cuz they all start at the center.
Then all 3 of them turn pink even if one of them touches the ray, even if the rest of the boxes are far away from the ray.
How can I make only the one that is touching the ray pink?)

Answer (score 0):

You first initialize the box material with a color(a default one).
Then you make 3 boxes with the same material.
When you change the color of the material all 3 boxes change color because they all use the same material instance.

if you initialize your boxes like this it should work:

```
const box1=new THREE.Mesh(boxGeo,new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial())
```

Because then every box gets their own instance of material and you can change them independently from each other.